# Python Web Scraping - Getting Text Between Span Tags

Tags: python, html

I am trying to get the word Cleveland out from this HTML information. [The HTML tags, IDs, and classes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrRRw.png) All I need to do is get the information in between the `<span>` and `</span>` keywords. I tried multiple methods to no avail. Here's my code that outputs the proper `Cleveland 52%`. Any advice on how to cut in between the `<span>` tags and just get `Cleveland`? Thanks!

```
home = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'covers-CoversConsensusDetailsTable-sideHeadRight'})
home = home.text.strip()
print(home)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'covers-CoversConsensusDetailsTable-sideHeadRight'}).find('span').text
```

find div then find span.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want only that div/ span you could search for the span within the first div you have there

`home = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'covers-CoversConsensusDetailsTable-sideHeadRight'})
cleveland = home.find('span').text.strip()`